# Flex s:text htmltext missing out/cutting the full html text

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flex4

I am trying to implement htmlText for a text component as the returned string is in html format (with the html tags etc). If I put a text=.... i get the full text, but with the tags (which i want converted to html). So i use htmlText=.... and it formats it fine, but cuts half the text from the variable. The text im supposed to get back has tons of html tags, and maybe its cutting it somewhere because of the tag its not able to escape... How do i fix this? Any solutions?

Comment: I don't know what `s:text` is referring to... What is your `s` namespace? Are you talking about a `Text`, `TextInput`, `TextArea`, `Label`, or something else?

Comment: ok something like ...<mx:Text htmlText="{model.ModelLocator.getInstance().selectedPost.body_full}" paddingLeft="3"    
        fontSize="14" textAlign="left"
        width="{ this.width }" height="{this.height}"
        paddingRight="3"  condenseWhite="false">
    </mx:Text>

Comment: If you could give an example of the html you pass in and then the output that results, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all tags are supported in the htmlText property. Here's a list of the tags that can be handled :

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/text/TextField.html#htmlText

An example though would make debugging easier :)